# Set final caret on JTextField

Tags: jtextfield, caret

How can I set a final caret on a text field? I managed to set it at the end of the text but when I run the application I can change it again.

[image]

Comment: You mean so that it stays at the end of the text and cannot be moved eg. with arrows?

Comment: Yes, I want it at the end of ":"